# Approximate/Fuzzy matching when we have a huge list

Tags: java

I have a table in mySql database containing the complete information of a user. Now, I want to find the record of the user on the basis of user name entered by user. And I want to make my matching intelligent for example if user enters "Bilal Ahmed" and the actual entry in table is "Bilal Ahmad". Notice there is the difference of just single character.
Soundex will be time consuming and will not effective too from accuracy point of view as I have 17 lakh records increasing dat by day ...
kindly suggest me how I can approach to this issue ?

Comment: Fuzzy matching will be more aggressive as it may match to some other user and too I think it will not work with such huge amount of data ...

Comment: You could use a full text search engine like [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/); if you're worried about scaling it you can investigate [katta](http://sourceforge.net/projects/katta/). Finally, you might just prefer [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Comment: And is there any other solution that we may implement programmatically like fuzzy, soundex or like etc. ????

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, I have implemented Apache Lucene. But it is just performing exact match. I have added 16 lakh documents in indexer to index it. Each document contains a username. Now I have a document containg username 'bilalahmed54' and I try to query 'bilalahmad54' (Just single character difference) but it didn't match it with any username while it should with document containing username 'bilalahmed54'. What is this matter ? am going on right track ?